# comapring compressed distribution per cohort

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, distribution

How can I easily compare the distributions of multiple cohorts?

Usually, https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html would be a great tool to visually compare distributions. However, due to the size of my dataset, I needed to compress it and only keep the counts.

It was created as:

```
SELECT age, gender, compress_distributionUDF(collect_list(struct(target_y_n, count, distribution_value))) GROUP BY age, gender
```

where `compress_distributionUDF` simply takes a list of tuples and returns the counts per group.

This leaves me with a list of

```
Row(distribution_value=60.0, count=314251, target_y_n=0)
```

nested inside a `pandas.Series`, but one per each chohort.

Basically, it is similar to:

```
pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2], 'bar':['first', 'second'], 'baz':[{'target_y_n': 0, 'value': 0.5, 'count':1000},{'target_y_n': 1, 'value': 1, 'count':10000}]})
```

and I wonder how to compare distributions:

- within a cohort `0` vs. `1` of `target_y_n`
- over multiple cohorts

in a way which is visually still understandable and not only a mess.

## edit

For a single cohort [Plotting pre aggregated data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585552/plotting-pre-aggregated-data-in-python/55585704#55585704) could be the answer, but how can multiple cohorts be compared (not just in a loop) as this leads to too many plots to compare?

Comment: Could you add another dataframe which represents your expected output.

Comment: No the idea is not to have another dataframe but rather a visual comparison of the distributions. I.e. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045750/python-distplot-with-multiple-distributions but with the compressed distributions and not the raw values

Comment: would a qqplot do? You basically want to check the distributional difference between  the groups: `target==0` and `target==1` and for each group you have the value and the count per value, correct?

Comment: Indeed I have these values and would need to check.

Comment: Would seaborn have a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Also, how would QQPlots work in case of this compressed data?

Comment: your `distribution_value` goes from 0 to 100? is it a percentile? and `count` is the count for that percentile or is a cumulative count?

Comment: No, it is not it is a real double metric value. Most values are between 50 and 70 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still quite confused but we can start from this and see where it goes. From your example, I am focusing on `baz` as it is not clear to me what `foo` and `bar` are (I assume cohorts).
So let focus on `baz` and plot the different distributions according to `target_y_n`.

```
sns.catplot('value','count',data=df, kind='bar',hue='target_y_n',dodge=False,ci=None)
```

[image: bars]

```
sns.catplot('value','count',data=df, kind='box',hue='target_y_n',dodge=False)
```

[image: box]

```
plt.bar(df[df['target_y_n']==0]['value'],df[df['target_y_n']==0]['count'],width=1)
plt.bar(df[df['target_y_n']==1]['value'],df[df['target_y_n']==1]['count'],width=1)
plt.legend(['Target=0','Target=1'])
```

[image: bar]

```
sns.barplot('value','count',data=df, hue = 'target_y_n',dodge=False,ci=None)
```

[image: barplot]

Finally try to have a look at the `FacetGrid` class to extend your comparison (see [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)).

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(df,col='target_y_n',hue = 'target_y_n')
g=g.map(sns.barplot,'value','count',ci=None)
```

[image: facetgrid]

In your case you would have something like:

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(df,col='target_y_n',row='cohort',hue = 'target_y_n')
g=g.map(sns.barplot,'value','count',ci=None)
```

[image: barcohorttarget]

And a qqplot option:

```
from scipy import stats
def qqplot(x, y, **kwargs):
     _, xr = stats.probplot(x, fit=False)
     _, yr = stats.probplot(y, fit=False)
 plt.scatter(xr, yr, **kwargs)

g=sns.FacetGrid(df,col='cohort',hue = 'target_y_n')
g=g.map(qqplot,'value','count')
```

[image: qqplot]

Comment: But that would only work for a single cohort i.e. I would have `n` such plots for each cohort.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I gave you 7 options. Which one is "that"?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler also, you can simply discriminate according to `cohort` instead of `target` but if you plot `n` different distributions in one plot it would probably be very messy