# Plotting different lines for different states on the same chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a distribution for the number of ___ across a few states.

I want to get all of the states on the same graph, represented by different lines.

Here is an example what my data looks like: you have the state ('which I want to filter lines by), the number of reviews (x axis), and the frequency of restaurants that have that many reviews (y axis)

```
State | num_of_reviews | Count_id
alaska        1              400
alaska        2              388
alaska        3              344
...
Wyoming      57              13
```

Whenever I try doing a simple line plot in seaborn or matplotlib, it just returns a messy graph.

Does anyone know a string of code where I easily can filter df['State']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have 50+ states, I wouldn't plot the distribution for each on the same plot as it would get really messy and hard to read. Instead, I would suggest to use a `FacetGrid` (read more about it [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)).

Something like this should do.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="State", col_wrap=5, height=1.5)
g = g.map(plt.hist, "num_of_reviews")
```

You can find other possible solutions and ideas on how to visualize your data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581469/comapring-compressed-distribution-per-cohort/55592709#55592709).

If none of these work for you then it might be helpful if you explain a bit better your problem and provide a desired output and a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Thank you, a much more logical option! I do get an error when trying to add the argument `height=1.5` however. Is that argument a new one?

Comment: @KyleMcComb nope, it's one of the argument to set the dimension of each facet. from the documentation: *height : scalar, optional

Height (in inches) of each facet. See also: aspect.

aspect : scalar, optional

Aspect ratio of each facet, so that aspect * height gives the width of each facet in inches*

Comment: Well it looks good without the argument, so no worries if i can't get it working. Thank you @gio